# How to Build Composite Condition in CodeDOM to execute Rules

Tags: .net, validation, codedom

I am trying to build Rules with my custom UI and execute with CodeDom for my workflow module.  I don’t want to use the Rules interface which is given with WF.  In order to build/ execute a Rule, I am creating a Condition and ThenAction/ElseActions.  At present I am able to execute a single condition successfully.  Means Suppose an **Order** Entity is there with the properties like **OrderID, Amount, NoOfItems, Discount, and TotalAmount.**

**Able to Build the Below condition:**

```
if (this.Amount > 1000)
    thisDiscount = 100;
```

**Building Left / Right conditions:**

```
CodePropertyReferenceExpression technologyRef = new CodePropertyReferenceExpression(thisRef, " Amount");

CodePrimitiveExpression wfConstant = new CodePrimitiveExpression(1000);

// if ( this. Amount > 1000)

CodeBinaryOperatorExpression cond = new CodeBinaryOperatorExpression();

cond.Left = technologyRef;

cond.Operator = CodeBinaryOperatorType.GreaterThanOrEqual;

cond.Right = wfConstant;

Rule rule = new Rule("rule1");

rule.Condition = new RuleExpressionCondition(cond);
```

**Not Able to Build the Below condition:**

```
if (this.Amount > 1000 && NoOfItems > 5)
    thisDiscount = 150;
```

Can anyone help me to build multiple conditions for a Rule?
 Means validation on multiple properties in a single IF statement.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Why can't you build the second condition? What have you tried?

Comment: My problem is, i am not getting how to add second part of condition ie " && NoOfItems > 5" to the first condition. How to add two conditions to the same rule with a selected operator in between two statements.  I am able to add multiple rules but not miltiple conditions to the same rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tree for your first condition would look something like this:

```
      <
     / \
Amount  1000
```

And that's exactly how you represented it in your code: one `CodeBinaryOperatorExpression` for the `<` and then an expression for each of the children. Doing the same for the second expression is almost the same, but the tree will be bigger:

```
        -----&&-----
       /            \
      <              >
     / \            / \
Amount 1000 NoOfItems  5
```

That is, you will have one `CodeBinaryOperatorExpression` that represents the `&&` (`CodeBinaryOperatorType.BooleanAnd`), whose left child will be the `<` node and its right child will be the `>` node.